# Is it possible to set a middle layer as an output layer in keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I would like to try out an idea about autoencoder.
The model is like this:

```
input (pictures) - conv2d - pooling - dense - dense(supervised output) - dense - conv - upsampling - output (pictures)
```

If it is possible to train the NN having desired outputs for `dense(supervised output)` and `output (pictures)`? In other words, I want to make a classifier-and-back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the Keras functional API (https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

A minimal example, where the model has 2 outputs, one from an intermediate layer, and one from the final layer:

```py
import keras
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))

intermediate = keras.layers.Dense(10)(input)
final_output = keras.layers.Dense(3)(intermediate)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[intermediate, final_output])
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please help me with an extention of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58374010/12213054